# Saving JSON to SQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql-server, json

I am storing JSON in a MsSql database, I am then passing it to Javascript via a PHP script, one of the JSON values is a format string that is passed to [jQuery-dateFormat](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat), "yyyy-MM-dd" for example.

It works great until i want to include extra text not part of the formatting string, specifically d, h, a or p characters. Fortunately there is a way to escape strings as part of jQuery-dateFormat, if I wrap the text in single quotes (') i am able to use the affected characters unsubstituted.

When I attempt to save the JSON with this additional value through my existing PHP script back to the database It doesn't work.

Now for some code, i use a standard `<textarea>` as an input for the JSON data and validate it on the server by using;

```
function fValidJson($input) {
    json_decode($input);
    switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            return $input;
            break;
        default:
            return false;
            break;
    };
};
```

if `$input` passes the test I update the database using;

```
odbc_exec($conn, $update);
```

without any data for the dateFormat format `$update` looks like this;

```
update data set json = '{"folder": "example"}' where id = 1
```

with dateFormat data `$update` can look like this;

```
update data set json = '{"folder": "example", "format": "report-yyyy-MM-dd"}' where id = 1
```

Ordinarily this would be fine except i want to preserve the "p" in "report" and it gets converted to "a.m./p.m." by jQuery-dateFormat. escaping the the "p" once;

```
update data set json = '{"folder": "example", "format": "re\'p\'ort-yyyy-MM-dd"}' where id = 1
```

gives me an error with `json_last_error()`, while escaping it twice;

```
update data set json = '{"folder": "example", "format": "re\\'p\\'ort-yyyy-MM-dd"}' where id = 1
```

gives me an error updating the database table row. escaping it a third time returns the same problem with `json_last_error()`.

This behavior is expected though. JSON can't contain single quotes (') and the single quote (') confuses SQL. So what are my other options for saving this JSON string to SQL?

Comment: `Escape` your input, for example, or use prepared SQL statement

Comment: Why do you need the string 'report' as part of the format, and not just the date forrmat?

Comment: @BrianGlaz because i want to cut down on work for myself, the formatted output is actually a filename, and sometimes there is normal text along with dates in the filename. It also makes it more flexible if i wanted something like "jan report 2015".

Comment: @bodi0 I have been escaping my input, i think. Can you elaborate?

Comment: when / where is it being transformed by jquery date format? After you get it from the DB and try to display on the front end?

Comment: @doveyg - Have you heard of `http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php` ?

Comment: @bodi0 yes, adding slashes manually didn't help, why would a function? the problem i am experiencing is that the act of escaping isn't having the desired effect.

Comment: try PDO with prepared statements, then you won't have to bother with quotes and slashes

Comment: Or in alternative, a document-based database, which works nicely with json, like mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

update data set json = '{"folder": "example", "format": "re''p''ort-yyyy-MM-dd"}' where id = 1

The quotes before and after p in report are two single quotes. Cause single quotes are allowed in json and don't need to be escaped, but in mssql you need to escape a single quote with two single quotes.

Comment: Did you try it? Your link says, that single quotes don't need to be escaped, but escaped single quotes are not allowed.

Comment: I did try it, and it did work. However, when I read it back I only get one quote. The output is also copied into the input so it causes errors again if i try to submit. Unsure at this time if I will put the double quotes back using `str_replace()` or use a prepared statement...

Comment: what if json variable will contain a backslash?